# Open applications don't survive hibernation (sleep). Is there a fix?

Tags: suspend, swap, hibernate

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (on Dell Inspiron 3505) with swap file of 16GB which I recently created after deleting the default 2GB swap file as per the instructions in [Swap FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).

*Q1.* My open applications are still closed when I start after a hibernation. Is this normal? And/or, is there a fix?

*Q2.* Also, after the hibernation pressing the power button alone is not enough to wake up the laptop, I'm required to press power on button only after I plug in the power supply. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: @user535733 nothing in crash log. /sys/power/state has `freeze mem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both symptoms you describe indicate hibernation is not properly working on your system. Indeed, on resuming, your system should be restored the way you left it. Also the way you need to bring back your system to live suggest malfunction. Instead of resuming, a system reboot is happening.

Hibernate in known not to be quite reliable in Ubuntu, due to many differences in hardware, with details not disclosed by the manufacturers. This is why hibernation is, in many Linux distributions, disabled by default.

You thus will, likely, not be able to use hibernation. You are more likely to be able to use stand-by instead. This works on far more machines. In that state, RAM is preserved. To achieve that, the computer still uses a very small amount of power while in sleep mode. This is not suited for a longer term, but is a reasonable alternative to hibernate for shorter period (including a night). Benefit is that a system resumes much faster from sleep than from hibernate (in case that works).